# Wordpress : Access admin page during maintenance mode

Tags: wordpress, maintenance-mode

I have my WP site up and running. When it is time to release new changes, I turn my site into maintenance mode. But admins cannot access to the admin page to do their release related work.
I found that if I remove maintenance mode, they can access to the admin page.

Is there any solution to this problem? I want my site's admin page to be accessible while in maintenance mode.

The site is hosted in two ec2 instances in AWS

I am using wp cli command to enter in maintenance mode

```
wp maintenance-mode activate
```

Comment: How are you putting the site into maintenance mode, are you using a plugin? If so then check the plugin documentation to see what settings to use to allow admin access.

Comment: Updated question description

Comment: Try using a plugin like [Coming Soon Page, Under Construction & Maintenance Mode](https://wordpress.org/plugins/coming-soon/) which disables the frontend with a message for users who are not logged in, or [WP Maintenance Mode](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-maintenance-mode/) which does the same except it also lets you choose what lever of user can access it e.g. admins only.